# Expect - Spawn exiting after sometime

Tags: bash, expect

I written a script for sftp. Its working fine for few seconds. But exiting after few seconds. I tried in so many ways but cant able to figure out the problem. Here is my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set now [clock seconds]
set now [expr {$now - 3600}]
set date [clock format $now -format {%Y%m%d%H}]

set SOURCE "/home/sms/SMSC-Sec-2.0.7.0_MT/cdrs/"
spawn sftp root@10.167.250.75
  expect "password:"
     send "teledna\r"
     sleep 1
     expect "sftp>"
        send "cd /home/sms/CDRS-Noida \r"
        expect "sftp>"
           send "pwd \r"
           expect "sftp>"
               send "mput $SOURCE/DNA-AegisGw-CDR_PREPAID_$date*.log  \r"
               expect -exact "sftp>"
               send "quit \r"
send "I am here"
```

Output:

```
spawn sftp root@10.167.xx.xx
root@10.167.xx.xx's password:
Connected to 10.167.xx.xx.
sftp> cd /home/sms/CDRS-Noida
sftp> pwd
Remote working directory: /home/sms/CDRS-Noida
sftp> mput /home/sms/SMSC-Sec-2.0.7.0_MT/cdrs//DNA-AegisGw-CDR_PREPAID_2017031618*.log
Uploading /home/sms/SMSC-Sec-2.0.7.0_MT/cdrs//DNA-AegisGw-CDR_PREPAID_201703161800_499_10.170.xx.xx_AS.log to /home/sms/CDRS-Noida/DNA-AegisGw-CDR_PREPAID_201703161800_499_10.170.xx.xx_AS.log
/home/sms/SMSC-Sec-2.0.7.0_MT/cdrs//DNA-AegisGw-CDR_PREPAID_201703161800_499_10.170.xx.xx_AS.log   2% 1088KB 104.3KB/s   06:39 ETA[root@smsc admin]#
```

Exited after few seconds say 5 like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're `mput`ing many files it's expected to take quite a while. So try using a longer `timeout` (default: `10`) after `mput`:

```
send "mput $SOURCE/DNA-AegisGw-CDR_PREPAID_$date*.log \r" 
expect -timeout 600 -exact "sftp>"
```

or you can also set the global `timeout`:

```
set timeout 600
spawn ...
```

And an infinite `timeout` may be specified with the value `−1`.

Comment: The command `expect -exact "sftp>"` will complete (means it'll run the next command that follows) when it sees the expected pattern or it times out waiting for the pattern.

Comment: Is there anyway to wait until the sftp get finished??? I cannot rely on hardcode value because some days its take 10 minutes and some days two hours also..

Comment: `set timeout -1` for infinite timeout. updated the answer.

Comment: the `sftp` process will not finish on its own unless you type `quit`.

Comment: I am sending quit at the end. Will it not work to end the process

Comment: your `send quit\r` can finish the process for sure. but you have to wait for the previous `mput` command to complete (by `expect`ing the `sftp>` prompt) before sending `quit`, just like when you're manually interacting with the `sftp` session.

Comment: a bit more nicely: `send quit\r; expect eof`